# read multiple schemas through a Delta share made on top of Unity catalog that involves 400+ concurrent updates in a streaming way

Tags: apache-kafka, databricks, streaming, amazon-kinesis, delta-live-tables

How to read multiple schemas through a Delta share that involves 400+ concurrent updates in a streaming way.

DLT seems to be have a limitation on 100 concurrent updates on a pipeline. Initially i thought of creating multiple independent streams in a single pipeline. Is kafka or Kinesis better option?